# Windows Forms form opens in the background if I open an OpenFileDialog in its Load event

Tags: c#, winforms

I need the user to select a file to open before they can use the main form in the program I'm writing. I wrote the following in the form's load event handler:

```
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (openXmlFileDialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
        Application.Exit();

    fileName = openXmlFileDialog.FileName;
    Activate();
}
```

After this, MainForm appears in the background in spite of calling Activate() on it.

Another problem is that if the user presses Cancel and Application.Exit() is called, it has no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the code inside the `Shown` event instead.

Answer (score 1):

Do this in **`Program.cs`**

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    OpenFileDialog o = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (DialogResult.OK == o.ShowDialog())
    {
        Application.Run(new Form1(o.FileName));
    }
    else
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

In **`Form1.cs`**

```
string filename;
public Form1(string filename)
{
    this.filename=filename;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```